# gem install libxml-ruby: fatal error: 'plist/Node.h' file not found

Tags: rubygems, libxml-ruby

Trying:

```
sudo gem install libxml-ruby -n /usr/local/bin
```

Output:

```
Password:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing libxml-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/libxml-ruby-3.1.0/ext/libxml
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180316-738-nk2zon.rb extconf.rb
checking for libxml/xmlversion.h in /opt/include/libxml2,/opt/local/include/libxml2,/usr/local/include/libxml2,/usr/include/libxml2... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-xml2-config
    --without-xml2-config
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:524:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1144:in `block in find_header'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1143:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:28:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/libxml-ruby-3.1.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/libxml-ruby-3.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/libxml-ruby-3.1.0/gem_make.out
```

Opening the logs:

```
open /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/libxml-ruby-3.1.0/mkmf.log
```

Output:

```
"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/universal-darwin17 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS -iwithsysroot /usr/local/libressl/include conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib -L.             -L /BuildRoot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.Internal.sdk/usr/local/libressl/lib -L/BuildRoot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.Internal.sdk/usr/local/lib   -arch x86_64 -arch i386   -lruby.2.3.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:36:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/defines.h:45:11: warning: non-portable path to file '<String.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
# include <string.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
          <String.h>
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:36:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/defines.h:45:
/usr/local/include/string.h:25:10: fatal error: 'plist/Node.h' file not found
#include <plist/Node.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

Configuration:

- macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
- Xcode 9.2 (development tools are installed)
- gem 2.7.6

Note: I have the exact same error with:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -n /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the mkmf.log, I got a hint from:

> warning: non-portable path to file '<String.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk

And effectively, the error is from the `/usr/local/include/String.h` file, which may not be the intended `<String.h>` file. And this file is mysterious because it wants to include `<plist/Node.h>`, but `/usr/local/include/plist/` doesn't exist.

Actually, I found something else interesting:

```
brew doctor
```

> **Warning**: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
>   If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
>   building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
>
> Unexpected header files:
>     ...
>     /usr/local/include/String.h
>     ...

So I simply listed those unexpected headers files:

```
brew doctor 2> doctor.txt
```

I manually trimmed the top content of doctor.txt to only keep the list of files. Then I deleted those:

```
sed 's/^  //g' doctor.txt | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 rm
rm doctor.txt
```

Then both installation issues were fixed (libxml-ruby and nokogiri).

Comment: Got the same error when installing fastlane using
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin fastlane. on High Sierra. Resolved by following ur steps. Thanks.